# In multi variable linear regression when we do backward elimination why do we concede the p value of each variable

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

In multi variable linear regression when we do backward elimination why do we concede the p value of each variable? How does the p value help us determine to include it or not? Is it because we have the null hypothesis of all variables having a significant impact on the value of y and if for a particular variable if its p value is less than the 0.05 the null hypothesis is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the p-value is conceded in multi-variable regression problems is because the correct null hypothesis value for each parameter depends on the expectation function and where the parameter lies within it.  Since this function can give vastly different results depending on the parameter, it is basically impossible to have a single hypothesis test working for the models.

Another option to look at instead of the p-value for these types of problems is the confidence interval for each estimated parameter.  This will give a much more meaningful result than a single hypothesis test.